# Can a SSO service (Custom STS, WIF) be implemented so that it is highly available (clustered or in a web farm)?

Tags: .net, wcf, load-balancing, wif, sts-securitytokenservice

I recently asked a question here: [Implementing SSO in a .NET Web Farm for several e-commerce websites with WIF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678791/implementing-sso-in-a-net-web-farm-for-several-e-commerce-websites-with-wif)  that outlines the details behind my next question.

A brief summary of the question/solution is that a series of web sites needing a SSO solution could be implemented using WIF with a custom STS to validate users against a SQLMembershipProvider of some kind.  In developing a diagram for this system, another issue presented itself.

The purpose behind the idea of web servers in a web farm is to eliminate a single point of failure (SPOF) for the websites resulting in a more reliable delivery of service.  Similar strategies are well documented for database servers and e-mail servers.  Is it possible to implement a SSO solution without introducing a single point of failure into an existing highly available environment using a custom STS and WIF?  What additional steps / strategies would need to be implemented in order to remove this SPOF?

More or less the questions are:

- Can a custom STS be placed into a load-balanced environment?
- Can WIF be placed into a load-balanced environment (without using a third party implementation like Azure)?
- What are the specific technological issues that would need to be addressed in order to accomplish this (or could it be done in the same way that web servers are)?
- Is this AT ALL a good idea?  What are some potential issues?

I have done quite a bit of research online and am unable to find a complete answer to this question.  I am still new to claims based authentication and federated identities so forgive me if I am vague or obtuse.

Am I trying to fit a square peg in a round hole?

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•Can a custom STS be placed into a load-balanced environment?

Yes - although you may need "sticky sessions"

•Can WIF be placed into a load-balanced environment (without using a third party implementation like Azure)?

WIF is just a set of .NET classes that is added as a reference in a VS project. It enables the application to be claims-enabled. You can't deploy WIF "on its own". You deploy the claims-enabled application.

•What are the specific technological issues that would need to be addressed in order to accomplish this (or could it be done in the same way that web servers are)?

For ADFS with a server farm:
"Secondary federation servers store a copy of the AD FS configuration database from the primary federation server, but these copies are read-only. Secondary federation servers connect to and synchronize the data with the primary federation server in the farm by polling it at regular intervals to check whether data has changed. The secondary federation servers exist to provide fault tolerance for the primary federation server while acting to load-balance access requests that are made in different sites throughout your network environment."

Not sure how much of this is AFDS functionality and how much is standard SQL Server functionality? You can use SQL Server to configure two or more servers to work together as a server cluster to ensure that your custom STS is made highly available to service incoming client requests.

•Is this AT ALL a good idea? What are some potential issues?

From memory, the only issue we came across was the issue of "sticky sessions".

Also, refer [ADFS 2.0 High Availability and High Resiliency Walkthrough](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1841.aspx)

Update: Have a look at [Programming Windows Identity Foundation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627185). The issue is that WIF session cookies are protected by the machine key. Vittorio suggests:

- Sticky sessions
- Synchronise machine keys
- Use the SSL certificate on each machine

There's a section in the book about developing custom STS. I recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

- Can a custom STS be placed into a load-balanced environment?

There's no reason you can't deploy a custom STS into a web farm.  The passive federation endpoint is simply a website that your WIF relying party will redirect to when it needs to authenticate.  Therefore you would simply deploy multiple instances of the STS web site into the web farm.

- Can WIF be placed into a load-balanced environment (without using a third party implementation like Azure)?

As nzpcmad mentioned, you will need to synchronize machine keys between your relying party applications in the load balanced environment.  Since the SAML token is encrypted using the machine key, the application needs to decrypt it using the same key.

- What are the specific technological issues that would need to be addressed in order to accomplish this (or could it be done in the same way that web servers are)?

See other responses.

- Is this AT ALL a good idea? What are some potential issues?

Yes, high availability and redundancy are a very good idea.  ADFS has built-in capabilities for working in a web farm, but for a custom STS you'll just need to make sure the configuration for your STS is consistent between servers.  I would recommend storing the configuration in a database if possible.